# Sharing scanner from linux with windows

Tags: networking

I want to share scanner of Cannon G2000 printer connected with Linux (Fedora 35) to Windows 10 on same wifi connection. How can I do it?

Comment: http://usbip.sourceforge.net/ https://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/

Comment: Please edit your post to include the Linux distribution and version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first set up SANE on Linux so that the scanner works on the Linux system locally. The correct SANE scanner backend component for Canon G2000 seems to be `sane-pixma`, [documented here](http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-pixma.5.html). You'll get SANE on Fedora by using Fedora's standard package management tools to install the `sane-backends` and `sane-frontends` packages.

After that, you can set up [the `saned` service](https://penguin-breeder.org/sane/saned/) on the Fedora system to share the scanner over the network. Note that this is available as the `sane-backends-daemon` package on Fedora, so you won't need to follow the source-code-based installation instructions on the page linked above.

On Windows, you could then use the [wiasane driver](https://github.com/mback2k/wiasane) to allow Windows to connect to `saned` and use the scanner. WIA is the modern Windows scanner API that allows Windows applications to accept input from a scanner.

For older Windows systems, there is also a [SaneTwain driver](https://sanetwain.ozuzo.net/) but it is 32-bit only and apparently no longer actively maintained. SaneTwain is known to not work with 64-bit Windows applications. (TWAIN is the older Windows scanner API.)

Alternatively, you could set up a web-based network scanner user interface: the simple [`scanserv`](https://github.com/sbs20/scanserv) or the more fancy (and more complex to set up) [`scanservjs`](https://github.com/sbs20/scanservjs). These don't seem to be available as packages for Fedora 35, so you would have to install a web server (e.g. Apache) using Fedora's package manager, and then follow the instructions on the Github pages linked above to set up either the PHP-based `scanserv` or the nodejs-based `scanservjs`.

This is going to be more complicated than using `saned` and wiasane, but it would allow you to use the scanner from any device that has a web browser.

You can now also go the other way, and share a Windows Scanner With Linux, MacOS, Android, ChromeOS  and more over the industry standard driver-less eSCL (aka AirScan) protocol. The good news is that the scanner need not be Linux/SANE compatible. If it works in windows you can share it as an eSCL scanner. See http://scannershare.com

Comment: Except using wiasane driver I would recommend SANEWinDS [link]http://sourceforge.net/projects/sanewinds/[link] as the other package have some issue with it